# Compose Pager `animateScrollToPage()` not working with pages that request focus

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

The title is pretty much the gist of the issue. I am designing an onboarding flow in which every page contained within has a `TextInputField` that requests focus upon first composition.

Using `animateScrollToPage()` in this scenario leads to unexpected behaviour: pages not being scrolled all the way or pages being skipped entirely.
Removing the focus requesting or using `scrollToPage()` instead of `animateScrollToPage()` fixes the issues.

This behaviour is easy to reproduce on both the deprecated `Accompanist` Pager and the one introduced into foundation since `1.4.0`.

I was wondering if anyone has a potential solution to this issue or if it is just an inherent issue of `Compose`. Any suggestions/opinions are appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: You can check if currentPageOffset is zero before requesting focus and current page. You can refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76182265/how-can-i-handle-with-multiple-textfield-focus-in-jetpack-compose-pager/76183955#76183955) for working demo.

Comment: @Thracian Thanks a lot! I managed to get it to work. Honestly didn't think to manually check for the settled state of the pager. Please feel free to post it as an answer and I'll mark it as accepted.